# React Highcharts not Updating

Tags: highcharts, state, use-effect, use-state, react-highcharts

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const BarChart = () =>  {
    const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
    var optionsInitial: Highcharts.Options = {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
          title: {
            text: null
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
          },
          labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: -40,
          y: 80,
          floating: true,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor:
            '#FFFFFF',
          shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
          type: "bar",
          name: 'Year 1800',
          data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
          type: "bar",
          name: 'Year 1900',
          data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
          type: "bar",
          name: 'Year 2000',
          data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
        }, {
          type: "bar",
          name: 'Year 2016',
          data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
        }]
      }

      const [options, setOptions] = useState<Highcharts.Options>(optionsInitial)
      React.useEffect(() => {

        fetch(`${API}Clientcomparison/GetSentiment`, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("@token"),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then((res) => {
    
            return res.json()
          })
          .then((res : Array<object>) => {
            debugger
            let optToUpdate = optionsInitial;
            let seriesToUpdate: any[] = [];
    
            res.forEach((i:any)=>{
              seriesToUpdate = seriesToUpdate.concat([
                {
                type: "bar",
                name: i.categorycount,
                data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
    
              }
            ])
            })
               
            optToUpdate["series"] = seriesToUpdate
            setOptions(optToUpdate)
            console.log(res)
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    
    
    
    
      }, []);
    return (
       
    <HighchartsReact
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={options}
 
     

  />
    )
}


export default BarChart;
```

I have tried multiple solutions but not working.

I tried

- updateArgs={[true, true, true]}
- allowChartUpdate={true}
- oneToOne={true}

but no luck.

I am rendering chart first time with hard coded data, then sending API call to fetch data in **useEffect** and updating the state. I can see in debug tool that state is updated but it is not reflecting.

Comment: Hi @Usama Alvi, The update seems to work correctly here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo2-cgun2?file=/demo.jsx but I am not sure what is a sample response from API. Could you adapt the above example to show the problem?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Indeed it is working at the link, I can not call API from your provided link since that is not deployed yet and at the moment is at local environment. I'm not sure what other factors are interfering here bcz code seems quite straight forward

Comment: You don't need to call a real API, you can simulate it. Only the response is important.

Comment: This is what the response is, https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo2-forked-4dvh1?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: One more thing I'd like to point, im using typescipt not javascript

Comment: Hello @Usama Alvi, Thanks for the example! Using typescipt makes no difference here. Your example seems to work correctly, would you like to make it work in some other way?

Comment: @ppotaczek I made it an independent component containing highcharts and providing it data from other component(the one calling this component), so that works fine for me. However, I'm still not sure why the original one didn't work. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably the way of setting options in a state was wrong. You need to only save the new options in a state.